# Logic App bypass Null in filter query

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am building a Logic App that uses the Azure Resource connector to obtain a list of my resources. I would then like to filter the results to `Microsoft.Compute` resources that have a tag name and value of `stop` and `normal`.

Here is a snippet of resource that I receive back **without** any filters

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/Env1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVM1",
    "name": "MyVM1",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "tags": {
        "stop": "normal"
    }
},
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/LogicApp/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/DWSize-Check",
    "name": "DWSize-Check",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "tags": {}
}
```

As you can see, the bottom resource does not contain any tags, as with many others that will appear in the list

I use the standard `Compose` `Filter Array` connector to try and filter out from the `value` I receive back.

Here is the code that I wish to use for the filter command:

```
@and(contains(item()?['id'], '/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'), contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagName')), contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagValue')))
```

`variables('TagName')` and `variables('TagValue')` will be `stop` and `normal`, as show in the example tags listed in my results snippet.

However, because there is no tag values listed in other resources, such as `Microsoft.Logic/workflows`, I receive the following `null` error:

> InvalidTemplate. The execution of template action 'Filter_array'
>   failed: The evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression
>   '@contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagValue'))' failed: 'The
>   template language function 'contains' expects its first argument
>   'collection' to be a dictionary (object), an array or a string. The
>   provided value is of type 'Null'.'.

Would anyone know how to get around this?

I have tried similar queries to this `@contains(item().tags?.stop, variables('TagValue'))` just to see if it picks up anything, but I'm still blocked by a `null` response  :(

I tried the above with the help of the [Workflow Definition Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language), but still no dice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In addition to the answer posted by Thomas, I have performed the following (image below) to filter out `null` from the results and get to the `TagName`, but I am still unable to get to the `TagValue`, even if I use *contains*:

`@and(contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagName')), contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagValue')))`

or event just trying to look for `TagValue`

`@contains(item()?['tags'], variables('TagValue'))`

[image: Filtered]

Answer (score 2):

You can check for null and return an empty value (an empty array in your case).

You can replace `item()?['tags']` with this expression or create a variable :

```
if(equals(item()?['tags'], null), [], item()?['tags'])
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the code being 
`@and(contains(item()?['id'], '/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'), if(equals(item()?['tags'], null), [], item()?['tags']))` But I am prompted with error upon saving: `Failed to save logic app qwer. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Filter_array' at line '1' and column '80165' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'and(contains(item()?['id'], '/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'), if(equals(item()?['tags'], null), [], item()?['tags']))': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'.".'.`

Comment: Just for kicks I tried `@and(contains(item()?['id'], '/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'), if(equals(item()?['tags'], null), item()?['tags']))` and although it saved, it did mention that there should be 3 conditions. Strange how it doesn't like `[]` as the 2nd condition.