# Why is Logic Apps' if() expression executing both code paths simultaneously?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am getting failures on a Logic App because the if() expression is executing both the true and false paths. The false path is going to fail if it executes which is why I put it in an if() in the first place.

The expression is:

```
if(empty(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta']), null, formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta'], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

I've also tried:

```
if(equals(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta'], null), null, formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta'], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

The data is null:

```
...
"data": {
    "eta": null,
...
```

I've tested this by swapping out formatDateTime() with a string like 'is not null'. When I do this I get the expected output (null) and no failure.

**Update:** Someone from the Logic Apps team suggested the following as an alternative:

```
@if(empty(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta']), null, formatDateTime(coalesce(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta'], '1999-01-01'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

The usage of `coalesce()` is suggested here because it returns the first non-null result. So in this way I can at least be assured of providing a value to `formatDateTime()`.

Comment: I've recently had this issue myself, so I had to create 2 different Filter actions (one immediately after the other). The 1st filter action finds the null, then the 2nd filter action finds whatever else I was looking for. There was no way I could get around this, not even MS had an answer when I raised a support case. I figured there's no order in its processing, just whatever appears first when checking the JSON I was using.

Comment: @Beefcake That's painful. I've worked around it by making a condition and setting a variable. But I ran into a problem with this even because a string variable set as null returns an empty string instead of null. D'oh! (I don't have time today to open a question about that one...) I REALLY do like Logic Apps but I'm increasingly getting frustrated by the lack of basics.

Comment: Perhaps my Logic App question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240269/logic-app-bypass-null-in-filter-query  MS guy suggested something like this for me, which might help you? `@equals(empty(triggerBody()?['data']?['eta']), true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why?  Because that's the way it's written. ;)

What you are seeing is the expected behavior of `if()` execution in a LogicApp.  Someone from the LogicApp team mentioned this (Channel 9?, sorry don't recall) and don't expect it to change any time soon.

If either case might cause a runtime error, you'll need to do it in two steps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was able to confirm this with the Logic Apps team too.